# GestureDetector and Radio

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-radiobutton

I would like to execute some code when I press on Radio. GestureDetector works everywhere, but not here. If you run the code bellow, you get response (print) when tapping on Text, but not when tapping on Radio (both are wrapped in same GestureDetector).

Do you have any suggestions, how to overcome this (or explanation why this happens)?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int radioGroupValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => print("GestureDetector has been tapped."),
              child: new Row(children: [
                new Radio(
                  value: 0,
                  groupValue: radioGroupValue,
                  onChanged: _handleRadioValueWkotType,
                ),
                new Text("label 1"),
                new Radio(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: radioGroupValue,
                  onChanged: _handleRadioValueWkotType,
                ),
                new Text("label 2"),
              ])),
        ));
  }

  void _handleRadioValueWkotType(int value) {
    setState(() {
      radioGroupValue = value;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use `RadioListTile`?

Comment: `RadioListTile` does not offer any additional functionality, that would allow to capture "onTap" on radio button (how the text next to radio button behaves does not matter).

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I would like to achive, that the `GestureDetector` works "above" all widgets that it wraps. It does not work "above" `Radio` widget (but works "above" `Text` widget).

Comment: `Radio` has its own `GestureDetector` which "eats" any gestures on its area: just like those two detectors on red and green containers: `GestureDetector(
onTap: () => print('green tap'),
child: Container(
color: Colors.green,
alignment: Alignment(-0.5, 0),
height: 100,
child: GestureDetector(
onTap: () => print('red tap'),
child: Container(
color: Colors.red,
width: 200,
),
),
),
),
`

Comment: but if you see the above code and replace the outer `GestureDetector` with `Listener` it seems that raw events are propagated and you could use `TapGestureRecognizer` for taps detecting

Comment: Thanx @pskink. That's the solution and explanation. To summarize (for others): When a `GestureDetector` is wrapping another `GestureDetctor`, the wrapped (child) `GestureDetecors` "wins". (One) option to solve this is replacing outter `GestureDetector` with `Listener` (and using it's parameter `onPointerDown`).
I've found another solution on the internet (but it is not as simple as the one from @pskink): https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deep-dive-gestures-c16203b3434f (paragraph: So what if you wanted both the parent and the child to receive the pointer events?).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RadioListTile` widget which acts same as the `radio` widget, but it has extra `title` parameter where you can provide `text` which will be shown just beside the `radio` widget and also **clicking on the title text will behaves same as clicking on radio widget itself.**

```
RadioListTile(
              title: Text('Standard'),
              value: 1,
              groupValue: _selectedType,
              onChanged: (int value) {
                Select(value);
}),
```

[Check out official link and example](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html)

Comment: This is not the functionality I am looking for. I would like to execute some code whenever user taps on radio button (the circular area) - even if radio button is already selected. I would like to have a parameter `onTap` in widget `Radio` or `RadioListTitle`. `GestureDetector` should take care of that, but it does not. **This has nothing to do, how text next to radio button behaves.**

Answer (score 0):

The Radio button is already a clickable element, so you don't need to wrap it in a GestureDetector. It makes sense to wrap text that follows it in a GestureDetector, but not the button itself. One way to achieve what you want is to call some method normally onTap, but also when the value changes, which is inside the onChanged method itself used on the Radios, like so:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int radioGroupValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => eitherRadioTapped(),
              child: new Row(children: [
                new Radio(
                  value: 0,
                  groupValue: radioGroupValue,
                  onChanged: _handleRadioValueWkotType,
                ),
                new Text("label 1"),
                new Radio(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: radioGroupValue,
                  onChanged: _handleRadioValueWkotType,
                ),
                new Text("label 2"),
              ])),
        ));
  }

  void eitherRadioTapped(){
    print("Anything in the row has been tapped.");
  }

  bool _handleRadioValueWkotType(int value) {
    print("Radio has been tapped.");

    //Whatever happendeed, it was clicked, so call the extra method
    eitherRadioTapped(); 

    setState(() {
      radioGroupValue = value;
    });
    return false;
  }
```

You could even set the Radio's `onChanged` method to null on your own code, which makes the GestureDetector receive the event, but this would make the Radio grey and need other workarounds, setup separate GestureDetectors for each Radio element, which wouldn't be ideal and be less simple.

Comment: *"The best way to achieve what you want is to [...]"* use `RadioListTile`

Comment: @pskink I suggest you post an answer. I have never used RadioListTile, it seems simple, even though from the question I understood that OP wants something to happen on any tap, thus why he put the GestureDetector around the full row of radios, not just a single Radio button.

Comment: The solution George suggested is not complete: `Radio`'s parameter `onChanged` gets triggered only when user taps on unselected radio button, but when user clicks on selected one, nothing gets triggered (and I need also this).
The `RadioListTile` does not solove the problem either (it solves another problem: making the label also clickable as radio button, but I am not looking for this).
I am looking for a way, that some independent code gets executed whenever user clicks on area that `GestureDetector` wraps. Whenever I used this approach it worked, it just looks that `Radio` is exception.

Comment: This question has a appropriate solution. Please see the comment section of the question. Click "show more comments" to get the exact solution.